# Ternary operator with boolean variable C#

Tags: c#

I have a doubt with my C# code and I would like to have your mind about ternary operator with boolean variable.

I have this in my code:

```
bool EstDonneesFinancieresComplementaires = false;
if (groupeDeNotation.CodeAlgo == "BQ")
   {
       EstDonneesFinancieresComplementaires = true;
   }
```

But I would like to simplify this line by using ternary operator:

```
bool EstDonneesFinancieresComplementaires = groupeDeNotation.CodeAlgo == "BQ" ? true : false;
```

Visual Studio says "`? true : false;`" is useless. And purpose this:

```
bool EstDonneesFinancieresComplementaires = groupeDeNotation.CodeAlgo == "BQ"
```

Is is the same thing that my first code lines ? By default it's "false" and "true" only if `groupeDeNotation.CodeAlgo == "BQ"` ?

Comment: All this codes are equivalent.

Comment: Yes the value of your variable will be the same in both cases, thus it's equivalent.

Comment: What type of value do you think `groupeDeNotation.CodeAlgo == "BQ"` will produce?

Comment: `groupeDeNotation.CodeAlgo == "BQ"` is an expression that produce a bool value. It's perfectly valid to use that expression to assign the value of a bool variable.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever A boolean sure, but I don't know if I should initialize the variable as false before.

Comment: By the way, you could have simply wrote Unit Tests for both ... and see if they pass. _"but I don't know if I should initialize the variable as false before"_ a boolean can only be false or true, nothing in between. So if it doesn't resolve to true, it is going to resolve to false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, Visual Studio is correct.

Applying the operator `==` has a `bool` return type.

`groupeDeNotation.CodeAlgo == "BQ"` is a boolean expression itself, using it as a condition for a ternary operator like that is useless because you already have the condition value.

Plus, if it wasn't a boolean condition you wouldn't be able to use it for a ternary operator isn't it?

To be comprehensive, writing this:

```
bool result = groupeDeNotation.CodeAlgo == "BQ"
```

is the same as:

```
bool result = groupeDeNotation.CodeAlgo == "BQ" ? true : false
```

which is the same as:

```
bool result;
if (groupeDeNotation.CodeAlgo == "BQ"){
  result = true;
}else{
  result = false;
}
```